# Finding duplicates over two columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a correlation matrix produced with `corr <- cor(data, use = "pairwise.complete.obs")`. I used this code to get the data to a long format and filter for correlations > 0.1:

```
corr %>% 
  as_tibble(rownames = "From") %>% 
  gather(key = "To", value = "corr", -From) %>% 
  filter(!From == To) %>%
  mutate(corr_abs = abs(corr)) %>%
  filter(corr_abs > 0.1) %>% 
  arrange(-corr_abs)
```

The result, however, mentions every correlation twice. How could I remove those duplicates when the values are in two different columns?

## Output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 4
  From            To                corr corr_abs
  <chr>           <chr>            <dbl>    <dbl>
1 health.age      health.employed -0.393    0.393
2 health.employed health.age      -0.393    0.393
3 health.age      health.marital   0.212    0.212
4 health.marital  health.age       0.212    0.212
5 health.alcohol  health.gender    0.187    0.187
6 health.gender   health.alcohol   0.187    0.187
7 health.age      health.fruitveg  0.100    0.100
8 health.fruitveg health.age       0.100    0.100
```

## Expected

```
# A tibble: 8 x 4
  From            To                corr corr_abs
  <chr>           <chr>            <dbl>    <dbl>
1 health.age      health.employed -0.393    0.393
2 health.age      health.marital   0.212    0.212
3 health.alcohol  health.gender    0.187    0.187
4 health.age      health.fruitveg  0.100    0.100
```

## Data

```
corr <- structure(c(1, 0.0632225392922264, 0.0554804788901363, 0.0974838182384356, 
0.212473674076218, -0.0286618705621989, 0.0632225392922264, 1, 
0.0908529910265203, -0.0554639294179715, -0.0326865391045356, 
0.186574369192519, 0.0554804788901363, 0.0908529910265203, 1, 
0.0377351030257117, -0.392764651422931, 0.065822234809157, 0.0974838182384356, 
-0.0554639294179715, 0.0377351030257117, 1, 0.10048775378073, 
-0.0684000695994252, 0.212473674076218, -0.0326865391045356, 
-0.392764651422931, 0.10048775378073, 1, -0.0312405196930598, 
-0.0286618705621989, 0.186574369192519, 0.065822234809157, -0.0684000695994252, 
-0.0312405196930598, 1), .Dim = c(6L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(c("health.marital", 
"health.gender", "health.employed", "health.fruitveg", "health.age", 
"health.alcohol"), c("health.marital", "health.gender", "health.employed", 
"health.fruitveg", "health.age", "health.alcohol")))
```

Comment: @akrun Hmm. To get from output to expected would require exactly what you demonstrated as an answer to the first dupe link, no?

Comment: @MauritsEvers. Maybe, but I was trying to avoid that `apply` loop after creating the whole number of rows.  By removing the rows beforehand would be more efficient.   In the dupe link, the data is already created, but here, there is an option to manipulate at an earlier stage.  Anyway, you are right that it can be a duplicate

Comment: I think the difference is that in my case the answer below is a real improvement. It corrects the data before the duplicates are introduced, avoids the complicated apply + transposing + ordering and can be used with the dplyr logic.

Comment: @akrun Yeah, your answer definitely gives a much more comprehensive solution. Very nice (+1). I reopened the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option would be to `replace` the upper triangular values in the initial data to `NA`, then remove it with `na.rm = TRUE` from `gather`

```
corr %>% 
   replace(., upper.tri(., diag = TRUE), NA) %>%
   as_tibble(rownames = "From") %>% 
   gather(key = "To", value = "corr", -From, na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
   mutate(corr_abs = abs(corr)) %>% 
   filter(corr_abs > 0.1) %>% 
   arrange(-corr_abs)
# A tibble: 4 x 4
#  From           To                corr corr_abs
#  <chr>          <chr>            <dbl>    <dbl>
#1 health.age     health.employed -0.393    0.393
#2 health.age     health.marital   0.212    0.212
#3 health.alcohol health.gender    0.187    0.187
#4 health.age     health.fruitveg  0.100    0.100
```